# Header, Footer and Scrollable body inside showModalBottomSheet for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, constraints, flutter-layout, scrollable, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text('HEADER'),
          Scrollbar(
            thickness: 5.0,
            radius: Radius.circular(5.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('BODY'),
                  Text('BODY'),
                  Text('BODY'),
                  Text('BODY'),
                  Text('BODY'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text('FOOTER'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Ok no problem so far. I left out `isScrollControlled` on the `showModalBottomSheet` so that you cannot drag up to fill the screen. I want it to max out at half the viewport height (which I think is the default constraint?) I also want it to size to it's content up until it hits this max height. However if I add more widgets to the `SingleChildScrollView` `Column` it overflows:
[image]

I'm expecting the "body" to max out it's height with the remaining space in-between the header and footer and become scrollable but it is just growing unconstrained. What can I do to make only the "body" contents scrollable once the `showModalBottomSheet` has reached it's height limit?

Answer (score 7):

I just achieved it with a few changes. `isScrollControlled: true` for bottom sheet and `Flexible(child: ListView(...))` widgets together.

Try it, https://dartpad.dev/6f76b09c942f8c44d89504032c355ff5

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('HEADER'),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: List<Text>.generate(1000, (x) => Text("CHILD")),
            ),
          ),
          Text('FOOTER'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I only wrapped my `Scrollbar` in a `Flexible` and that addressed all my needs.